# Pandas multiindex - apply custom function to financial time series

Tags: python, pandas, apply, multi-index, covariance

I have the below multiindex dataframe `df`. Each of the matrices are covariances matrices.

```
                    AAPL        BA          MSFT
Date                
2020-09-11  AAPL    0.000442    0.000175    0.000181
              BA    0.000175    0.000464    0.000172
            MSFT    0.000181    0.000172    0.000297

2020-09-14  AAPL    0.000442    0.000175    0.000181
              BA    0.000175    0.000464    0.000172
             MSFT   0.000150    0.000145    0.000286
... ... ... ... ...
2020-10-22  AAPL    0.000441    0.000177    0.000184
              BA    0.000177    0.000469    0.000173
            MSFT    0.000184    0.000173    0.000299
90 rows × 3 columns
```

I need to apply a complex custom function to each matrix.

I can apply my custom function to a single inner dataframe (i.e to one single covariance matrix) using `df.loc["2020-09-11"].droplevel(level=0)`. It works.

Unfortunately, I am totally stuck if I try to apply the function to the entire multiindex dataframe.
How can I deal with the indexing and apply my function to every covariance matrix, iterating through the multiindex dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: if it works on a single slice it should be as simple as : `df.groupby('Date').apply(your_cust_func)`? (Though perhaps you'll need to first remove the outer level of the MultiIndex)

Comment: How can I remove the outer level? Thanks